# How to change Google compute instance primary network device eth0 netmask /32

Tags: linux-networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, eth0, netmask

When I create an instance in the default VPC, and check ifconfig, it says netmask is `/32`, as shown below:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.138.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 10.138.0.2
        inet6 fe80::4001:aff:fe8a:2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 42:01:0a:8a:00:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4728  bytes 39926123 (38.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3900  bytes 442039 (431.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The issue is the application I try to install does not allow `/32` subnet. I tried creating a test VPC network, but I cannot ssh to the instances anymore if I use that. If tried adding secondary ranges to default subnet without success. I have tried to expand the netmask with `sudo ifconfig eth0 10.138.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0`
only to have the ssh connection freeze (using web browser to ssh). And after that I cannot ssh to instance. What would be other approaches for this?

I see question here, but does not look like it has been answered: [Google Cloud Compute set /20 subnet mask to internal interface](https://serverfault.com/questions/826457/google-cloud-compute-set-20-subnet-mask-to-internal-interface)

Comment: Fix the broken application. I don't think you can make Google do networking differently.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this parameters are set that way to have a better integration with Google Cloud Platform.

Regarding why you can not SSH when you create a new VPC, you must create new firewall rules, as they only apply to one VPC, so the old firewall rules do not apply to the new VPC.

I strongly recommend to open an issue with the support of the application in order to have integration with Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting here from a Google search, here's what I found in GCE documentation. 
Verbatim quote:

To configure interfaces with a netmask other than /32, you should create an image using the flag --guest-os-features MULTI_IP_SUBNET and use it to create your instance. For example, if you are using a debian-9 based image, you can create an image using following command:

```
gcloud compute images create debian-9-multi-ip-subnet \
     --source-disk debian-9-disk \
     --source-disk-zone us-west1-a \
     --guest-os-features MULTI_IP_SUBNET
```